# no-Perl no-Kernel open3 cPanel Error message on CentOS7

Tags: shell, apache-http-server, centos-7, cpanel

I tried to install cPanel with the [latest.sh](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cc9v2t82tfp9rqh/latest) install file. but I got this error message:

2017-11-18 15:57:58  906 (DEBUG):   - ssystem [BEGIN]: /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/checkyum --nokernel --noperl
open3: exec of /usr/local/cpanel/scripts/checkyum --nokernel --noperl failed at /home/cPanelInstall/selfgz5059/install line 291.Removing /root/installer.lock.